# C# how to interpret this `this` in function definition?

Tags: c#, function, default-parameters

I guess I never looked careful enough at the code I added before. Can someone help elaborate on the signature of this function? It is from .net 3.5 code, there is no default parameter support. But this `this` behaves just like default parameter.  The function works just like `GetFocusedControl(Form parentForm=this)`.

```
public static Control GetFocusedControl( this Form parent_form)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: `GetFocusedControl` is an *extension method* for `Form` class; so you can use it as if `GetFocusedControl` is declared as `Form` method: `MyForm myForm = new MyForm(); ... var ctrl = myForm.GeFocusedControl(); ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension method which must be placed in a static class. Assuming that the namespace of this extension method is "visible" and you have a form, you can call this method with:

```cs
Form frm = new Myform();
Control control = frm.GetFocusedControl();
```

As if this method was a member of the form itself.

See also:

- [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)
- [C# - Extension Method (tutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

Comment: Are you sure you can't find a duplicate that explains this?